# Need Proof of Result on Endomorphism Rings of Elliptic Curves over Finite Fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves

In "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" by Silverman, the following result about the endomorphism rings of elliptic curves is proven:

[image]

Next a similar fact is mentioned in Schoof's "Nonsingular Plane Cubic Curves over Finite Fields":

[image]

The difference is, now the curve is over $\mathbb{F}_q$, so he narrows the possible quaternion algebras down to $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty,p}$. I tried to find a proof for this specific claim, but so far i couldn't find it.

Can someone provide a proof or a link to the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endomorphism ring of $E$ acts on the $\ell$-adic Tate module of $E$. If we tensor the endomorphism ring with $\mathbb Q$ we get this quaternion algebra, so it follows that the quaternion algebra acts on the $\ell$-adic Tate module tensored with $\mathbb Q$, which is $\mathbb Q_\ell^2$ as long as $\ell\neq p$.

If the quaternion algebra is ramified at $\ell$, then it cannot act on $\mathbb Q_\ell^{2}$, as tensoring with $\mathbb Q_\ell$ it is a rank $4$ division algebra, and thus cannot act on anything of dimension less than $4$.

Thus, the quaternion algebra is not ramified at any prime but $p$ and $\infty$. Because every quaternion algebra is ramified at at least two primes, it is ramified at those two primes.

Comment: A quaternion algebra tensored with $\mathbb{Q}_l$ is a rank 4 division algebra? Also, why is every algebra quaternion algebra ramified at at least two primes?

Comment: @José It is a rank 4 division algebra if it's ramified yes. It's certainly rank 4, and then becomes a division algebra / matrix algebra once you tensor depending on if its ramified / split. Or what do you think a ramified prime means? The number of ramified primes is known to be even, and can't be zero unless it is a matrix algebra.